# Contradictory values of $|e^{iz}|$

Tags: complex-numbers

$|e^{iz}|=\sqrt{\cos^2 z +\sin^2 z}=1$, However if $z=i$ then $|e^{iz}|=|e^{-1}|=\frac{1}{e}\neq 1$. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{-y}e^{ix}=e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)).$$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $$e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$$ However, $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are not real numbers, when $z\notin \Bbb R$. So, (if you really want to go that way) you should have actually used $$\left\lvert e^{iz}\right\rvert=\sqrt{(\Re\cos z-\Im\sin z)^2+(\Im \cos z+\Re\sin z)^2}\ne\sqrt{\cos^2z+\sin^2z}$$

Comment: what do the caligraphic letters in your post stand for?

Comment: Real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

$\exp(i z) = \cos(z) + i \sin(z)$, but $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ here are *complex* numbers, not *real* ones, with their own real and imagionary parts. So you can't compute $|\cos z + i \sin z|$ as $\sqrt{\cos^2 z + \sin^2 z}$.

Answer (score 0):

When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

1. $$\left|e^{\text{z}i}\right|=\left|e^{\left(\Re[\text{z}]+\Im[\text{z}]i\right)i}\right|=\left|e^{-\Im[\text{z}]+\Re[\text{z}]i}\right|=\left|e^{-\Im[\text{z}]}\cdot e^{\Re[\text{z}]i}\right|=\left|e^{-\Im[\text{z}]}\right|\cdot\left|e^{\Re[\text{z}]i}\right|$$
2. $$\left|e^{\Re[\text{z}]i}\right|=\left|\cos\left(\Re[\text{z}]\right)+\sin\left(\Re[\text{z}]\right)i\right|=\sqrt{\cos^2\left(\Re[\text{z}]\right)+\sin^2\left(\Re[\text{z}]\right)}=1$$
3. $$\left|e^{-\Im[\text{z}]}\right|=\frac{1}{\left|e^{\Im[\text{z}]}\right|}=\frac{1}{e^{\Im[\text{z}]}}$$